# I have the problem when I run the project in android studio in my phone

Tags: flutter, android-studio, run-app

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lNsE.png)

Before I updated my phone, the apps were working, but now they are not, My phone type is Redmi 9 and this is the last version 13.0.2.0 Stable MIUI 13

Answer (score 0):

I looks like you have set you phone to only charge over the usb connection, and not allow file transfer. You should be able to reset all allowances and blocks under development settings. You should also make sure that the cable is a data cable and not just a charging cable. To check if you set your connection to only charge, you should be able to pull down from the top twice to see your notificaitons, and in the bottom there should be a "charging via cable" notification or something along those lines, click that and set it to file transfer

Answer (score 0):

To run an app correctly on your device, you must follow these steps:
1- Allow developer mode.
2- Connect a cable.
3- Allow data transfer, not just charging.
4- Verify if your device is recognized (run "flutter doctor" and you will see the name of your device).
Finally, run the app on your device.